# In Baby Rudin's Theorem 1.1, why is it important that $S$ has the least upper bound property?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

In Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, we have the following theorem early on:

> **Theorem 1.11.** *Suppose $S$ is an ordered set with the least-upper-bound property, $B \subset S$, $B$ is not empty, and $B$ is bounded below. Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds of $B$. Then
>   $$
> \alpha = \sup L
> $$
>   exists in $S$, and $\alpha = \inf B$.*
>
> *In particular, $\inf B$ exists in $S$.*
>
> *Proof.* Since $B$ is bounded below, $L$ is not empty. Since $L$ consists of exactly those $y \in S$ which satisfy the inequality $y \leq x$ for every $x \in B$, we see that *every $x \in B$ is an upper bound of $L$.* Thus $L$ is bounded above. Our hypothesis about $S$ implies therefore that $L$ has a supremum in $S$; call it $\alpha$.
>
> If $\gamma < \alpha$ then (see Definition 1.8) $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $L$, hence $\gamma \not\in B$. It follows that $\alpha \leq x$ for every $x \in B$. Thus, $\alpha \in L$.
>
> If $\alpha < \beta$ then $\beta \not\in L$, since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $L$.
>
> We have shown that $\alpha \in L$ but $\beta \not\in L$ if $\beta > \alpha$. In other words, $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $B$, but $\beta$ is not if $\beta > \alpha$. This means that $\alpha = \inf B$.

Why it important that $S$ has the least upper bound property? Going through the proof, I don't see what would change if $S$ didn't have the LUBP.

Additionally, Rudin says beforehand that LUBP implies GLBP for an arbitrary set, but all I see is that if some set $A$ in a set $S$ has LUBP, there exists another set $B$ in $S$ that has GLBP. Is that the result we wanted?

Comment: "Our hypothesis about $S$ implies therefore that $L$ has a supremum in $S$" it's used here

Comment: The set $A$ in $S$ (mathematically $A\subseteq S$) does not have LUBP, rather the correct statement is "$A$ has LUB in $S$ and $S$ has LUBP". The theorem being proved is that *if some ordered set $S$ has LUBP then it also has GLBP*.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh But I thought we only proved that B has GLBP. How does that extend to S?

Comment: No the thing being proved is that "*if $B\neq \emptyset, B\subseteq S$ and $B$ is bounded below then $B$ has a GLB (not GLBP) in $S$*". This is what mean by the statement "*$S$ has GLBP*".

Comment: I think you are trying to mix the term LUB with LUBP and similarly GLB with GLBP. LUBP / GLBP is a property / feature which some set $S$ may have, but LUB, GLB are members of $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $S$ doesn't have the least-upper-bound property, then there is no reason why we can assert that $\sup L$ exists. That is the reason why Rudin wrote that “Our hypothesis about $S$ implies therefore that $L$ has a supremum in $S$”.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of an $S$ without LUBP and a $B$ such that $L$ has no supremum in $S$?

Comment: @TiwaAina Sure. $S=\mathbb{Q}$, with its usual order, and $B=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}\,|\,q^2<2\}$. Then $L=\left(-\infty,-\sqrt2\right)\cap\mathbb Q$, which has no supremum in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Tiwa $S=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and $L=(-\infty,0)$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, I see! One last question (this is also mentioned in my initial post): Rudin says beforehand that LUBP implies GLBP for an arbitrary set, but all I see is that if some set $A$ in a set $S$ has LUBP, there exists another set $B$ in $S$ that has GLBP. Is that the result we wanted?

Comment: @TiwaAina Rudin proves that if *every* non-empty set in $S$ has a supremum, then *every* non-empty set in $S$ has an infimum.

Comment: Why can we assume that every $B \subseteq S$ is bounded below?

Comment: @TiwaAina As far as I know, nobody assumed that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Part of the antecedent is "B is bounded below". It seems like this proves that if every non-empty BOUNDED-BELOW set in $S$ has a supremum, then every non-empty BOUNDED-BELOW set in $S$ has an infimum.

Comment: @TiwaAina No. The theorem states that **if** $B$ is non-empty and bounded below **then** it has an infimum.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If S has LUBP and $B \subseteq S$, is there a reason why we expect B to be bounded below? Rudin says LUBP implies GLBP; so this is only true when we know our subset B will be bounded below?

Comment: @TiwaAina No there is no reason to expect that $B$ is bounded below. That's why Rudin put that *as an hypothesis*.